# css style hex strings and Color.decode

Tags: java, colors, hex

[this article](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19183.html) suggests you can use `Color c = Color.decode("FF0096");` however this understandably throws an exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "FF0096"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:449)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:528)
    at java.lang.Integer.decode(Integer.java:958)
    at java.awt.Color.decode(Color.java:707)
```

What is the best way of converting a String in the format of "#FF0096" or "FF0096" into a java awt Color?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
Color c = Color.decode("0xFF0096");
```

or

```
Color c = Color.decode("#FF0096");
```

or

```
Color c = new Color(0xFF0096);
```

Comment: 6 hex digits max! I could not specify alpha.

Answer (score 9):

The [Color.decode](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#decode(java.lang.String)) method throws the [NumberFormatException](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) if the specified string cannot be interpreted as a decimal, octal, or hexidecimal integer

The string "FF0096" **without** the prefix of `0` or `0x` will be interpreted as a base 10 representation which does not work.

Comment: you are wrong to say that FF0096 prefixed with 0x does not work.

Comment: @pstanton: Thanks for pointing out..it was a typo. I've corrected it.

Comment: *0* prefix means octal and it's very unlikely anyone would like that for decoding colors

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for a similar way to do this in Android. For some reason, I couldn't find `Color.decode()` so I looked for an alternative. If you want to use a hex string to represent a color in Android, you can do the following:

```
String hexColor = "#142b44";
View row = findViewById(R.id.row);
int color = Color.parseColor(hexColor);
row0.setBackgroundColor(color);
```

More at [Color#parseColor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor(java.lang.String))

Comment: This question is about `java.awt.Color`, while you're using `android.graphics.Color`.