# JFreechart bars lots of color needed

Tags: jfreechart

I am plotting a barchart with 26 bars.I need different colors for the bars.So i need 26 colors.I found that color can be set by specifying 'Color.BLUE' 'Color.red' etc.
But are there 26 colors available like this?Is it possible to use colorcodes like '#66FF66'
I tried 'Color.#66FF66',which is not correct.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

JFreeChart defines several colors in org.jfree.chart.ChartColor.  You can use these if you like.  These are the colors it cycles through as you add additional datasets to your plot.

```
ChartColor.DARK_BLUE
ChartColor.DARK_CYAN
etc...
```

Or you can use java.awt.Color.  There are lots of ways to specify a Color--look at the javadoc for it.  Here's an example using RGB values:

```
//this will create light blue color
Color customColor = new Color(10,10,255); //r g b
```

Comment: thanks for this.But is there a way to use the color codes like '#00FF7F'?(instead of RGB)?

Comment: Google search is your friend.  Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339994/css-style-hex-strings-and-color-decode